# Setting Active Nav for Bootstrap in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How I can set active page nav for Bootstrap on my custom theme in my [WordPress site here](http://teddybearfamilychildcare.com/)?

Comment: It looks like NAV is not generated dynamically using PHP. Wordpress usually generates classes with dynamically generated NAV. But you can try one solution in PHP check if your current permalink is euqal to the NAV link then in its class `echo active`.

Comment: have you used wp_nav_menu function?

Comment: @Hi Ali, Thanks for your comment I already tried the <li <?php is_page( 'home' ){echo 'class="active"'}> but it didn't work!

Comment: @Bhumi, No, can you please let me know what is it?

Comment: This is wordpress function for displaying menu

Comment: Do I have to have it even if I have just very simple custom Menu? I mean I do not want to use WordPress built in Menu?